# Applying a Texture on a ply mesh

Tags: texturing, import

I've got a *.ply file from a interoral scanner. The *.ply-export comes with a texture file but the vertices of the mesh itself remain monochrome. I now need the texture put on the model (and if anyhow possible transfer the color to the vertices, but one thing after another). I tried some ways described in the net, but so far nothing matches my problem fairly.

Comment: Hello, could you describe what you have tried and where it failed ?

Comment: I importet the mesh into blender and created a new material and texture. After that switched to the Shading-tab and added the texture in the shader editor window. Thats what I had found on the Internet. The Texture is there, but small and repeated everywhere. Hope that helps. Let me know if you need more

Comment: Thank you for your help. This question can be closed. I found a workaround. I use MeshLab to transfer the texture colors to the vertices after I managed to put in on there correctly.

Comment: You can add that as an answer to your own question, it may help other people with the same problem in the future

Comment: Thanks, I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:

Open the ply model im MeshLab.

1. Go to Filters->Textures->Convert PerVertex UV into PerWedges UV
   (it may say it is missing the texture. If it does, copy the texture file into the
   MeshLab program directory. May be a bug or I am too stupid :P )
2. Then go to Filters->Texture->Transfer: Texture to Vertex Color....
   The standard values were enough for me.
3. Afterwards go to File->Export Mesh as... and export it as a *.ply. Make sure the vertex colors are checked in the following dialog and hit export.

In Blender import your freshly exported *.ply-file and change the view to "Vertex Paint". Et voila.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this ! :) Also after some time you will be able to accept your own answer, that will help in making it appear more in other people search queries

Comment: Thank you. (It sure feels a little bit weird to accept your own answer :) )

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've just been banging my head against the internet for the past few hours trying to do this. MeshLab crashed every time I tried to import, so I was just playing around with the shader nodes seeing if something would work.

I grabbed the Vertex node of the texture image I'm trying to use and tried connecting to bunch of different things. In the end, connecting it to the General node in Texture Coordinate did exactly what I wanted it to.

I am a total Blender noob, so I have no idea why this works. I never use Shader view or nodes, cause they're scary, but I'm posting here in case this helps someone else. [image: screenshot of Shader nodes with solution circled]